# Exam class: grading table without bonus questions

Tags: exam

According to the `exam` class, the grading table should only include the regular point, not the bonus points. However in the example below, the bonus question shows up in the grading table. How can I get rid of it?

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

 \question[4]
 TEXT
 \question[4]
 TEXT
 \question[4]
 TEXT
 \question[4]
 TEXT

 \bonusquestion
 TEXT

 \gradetable[v][questions]
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From `exam` document, I found a useful command that is

```
\begingradingrange{myrange} % at the start of the range and the command
\endgradingrange{myrange} % at the end of the range.
```

Using this command and  `\partialgradetable`, following code solves the problem.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\begingradingrange{first} % "first" is my choice for determining the range
 \question[4]
 TEXT
 \question[4]
 TEXT
 \question[4]
 TEXT
 \question[4]
 TEXT
\endgradingrange{first}
 \bonusquestion
 TEXT

 \partialgradetable{first}[v][questions]
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ok, this could be an acceptable answer. Is there also a way if there are more regular questions after the bonus question?

Comment: Well, again from `exam` document on page 84, `You can define as many grading ranges as you like, wherever you like. That is, grading ranges do not need to be nested; you can begin the range other range somewhere in the middle of the range myrange and then end the range other range after the end of myrange.`

Comment: If you define a second range, say named `second` wherever you want, `exam` class renders a second table with `\partialgradetable{second}[v][questions]`

Comment: yes, but that would be a second table. Isn't the `gradetable` supposed to show only the regular questions - in other words: is the behavior in my question a bug?

Comment: I said that it is the second table. I don't know is it a bug.